# Why couldn't parseltongue be learnt and could Dumbledore understand it?

Tags: harry-potter

Parseltongue could only be spoken by certain wizards such as Gaunts, Voldemort, Harry (temporarily) and Slytherin. Why couldn't it taught like French or Latin? Why wasn't it a subject in Hogwarts? Ron could mimic it to open Chamber of Secrets. During the 6th book Harry visits Gaunt's house with Dumbledore in memory where he sees them talking in parseltongue. Could Dumbledore understand them and how?

Comment: I count three questions here. "Why can't you learn parseltongue" is a good question, which I cover partially in my answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81081/how-did-ron-speak-parseltongue-and-re-enter-the-chamber-of-secrets). "Why isn't it a subject at Hogwarts" is covered [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43059/why-is-parseltongue-not-taught). "How could Dumbledore understand parseltongue" is covered [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15271/why-didnt-dumbledore-hear-the-basilisk). You should edit your question to focus on the first one

Comment: @JasonBaker  All three could be covered by a single question like "Can Parseltongue be learned like normal languages?"  If it can't, it would be obvious why it isn't taught in a class, and if it can, then Dumbledore's knowledge of it is obvious: he simply learned it.

Comment: Parseltongue could not be taught as a language because it was passed down via the Slytherin **blood line**. Ostensibly, it should be impossible for Dumbledore to speak Parseltongue. JKR explains his ability to *understand* Parseltongue as being due to his sheer brilliance.

Comment: @Slytherincess: there's a world of difference between being able to hear (and understand) a human speaking Parseltongue, and being able to hear a snake speak at all, in any language. Dumbledore could do the former, but Chamber of Secrets shows that he couldn't do the latter.

Comment: If it can't be learnt, Parseltongue can at least be imitated, as demonstrated in The Deathly Hallows when Ron opens the Chamber of Secrets.

Comment: @Martha -- I agree with you. I don't think I suggested otherwise, but rather was giving JKR's explanation for why Dumbledore could understand Parseltongue.